# Why can't we put all masters in one Master table in Database?

Tags: database, ms-access

We are designing a small database in MS Access 2010 and we have like 3 master attributes
Lets take for example we have Country, State and Tastes. Instead of designing master table for each attribute, we have come up with one table like below

```
ID  Value       Attribute
1   USA         Country
2   UK          Country
3   Illionis    State
4   Wisconsin   State
5   Sweet       Taste
6   Sour        Taste
```

We are using self joins and getting what is required. 
Does anyone think that, it is not a good database design, if yes please explain

Comment: That's a design anti-pattern. It's called "one true lookup table". Search for that term. Interesting enough this has just been discussed on the Oracle mailing list: http://www.freelists.org/post/oracle-l/Database-Design-Best-Practice-help and the Postgres mailing list: http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/Database-design-best-practice-td5733881.html

Comment: I forgot about that name. Here's a good article to read up on that topic: http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/look-up-tables-in-sql-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reasons against:

1) Extra storage space to store a field indicating what type it is (cancelled out by the primary keys on each table when having multiple tables, but then you'll need to store the type as an (small) integer type, not a string type).

2) Extra storage space for fields that are not applicable to certain types (N/A if the above is not just an example, and there won't be more fields, but then I'm questioning the rest of your DB design, and extensibility is always worth a consideration).

3) Reduced performance to select the applicable rows.

4) An index would obviously be required on `Attribute` (otherwise (3) is a performance killer), so - reduced performance on update and delete statements.

5) Bad database design - don't combine concepts that don't belong together

**EDIT:**

6) Database integrity - what stops you from just inserting invalid data into the `Attribute` field. Admittedly, you can have another table with attributes and make `Attribute` a foreign key to that table, which is a bit messy and confusing to figure out what's going on sometimes.

7) Foreign keys - doing this will just be a mess, not too mention you can't enforce database integrity and likely speed implications.

8) Visualization - any table diagrams will have to be manually drawn or edited because an automatic generating tool (most likely) won't be able to account for this type of design.

Comment: Thank you Dukeling, another thing i forgot to mention is we are designing it in Access DB as it is a very small database and used by standalone Windows App.

Comment: And what's even more important: you can't have foreign keys to ensure that the a lookup value is only used in the intended table.

Comment: A bad database engine is no excuse for a bad database design :)

Comment: (I think) people don't care about good design all too often because they think what they're writing will never become large (or think taking shortcuts for this one small thing will not affect performance of the entire app), but then it does, and then they need to rewrite everything to get performance up to standard or spend a lot more on powerful hardware. Not to mention that doing things wrong for small things generally leads to doing things wrong for large things.

Answer (score 0):

If I need to get a list of states by country, how do I do that? With your design, you can't do that, other than by adding an additional table. If you split into entity types, e.g. Country, AdministrativeDivision and Taste, you can store the appropriate attributes per entity, instead of complicated join tables. The resulting SQL is easier to read and debug.

There is really no reason to attempt to "optimize" by minimizing the number of tables. Any modern database engine will not suffer a performance penalty from additional tables. Your design may in fact trigger a performance penalty. Depending on how many different entities you try to jam into that table, you may end up making it so large that the entire table can't fit into memory, thus forcing the database to page from disk when performing selects and joins on this table. A good rule of thumb might be if you can't make a reasonable guess about what query plan your database might use to get the data you are requesting, just follow accepted SQL best practices.

There is one situation I can think of where this design could be acceptable, and that's if you need to provide a store for users to add their own categories and values at runtime.